# How to refresh Javascript code in IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, execute, p5.js

So, I am trying to experiment with making a code editor. I have an IFrame with a preview window that is linked to another HTML document in my webpage where the code would be executed. (I need to execute code with the p5 library) This is the code when I click on "run code" button -

```
try {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.id = "code"
    script.text  = code
    $('#preview').contents().find('#codeplaceholder').html(script)

    $('#preview').contents().find('#code')
    document.getElementById('preview').contentWindow.location.reload();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
```

and here is the tags in my HTML preview document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script id = "p5" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="codeplaceholder">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

so what's wrong? Then I try to run code with the p5 library, nothing happens. 
I am out of ideas. Seems like "Alert" messages work, but p5 is just really stubborn...

Comment: Where is  '#preview' element? You're requesting content from it, where it is ? Preview should be htzml element of some kind ...

Comment: Can you share jsfiddle link with your code? Not sure what code element is having.

Comment: the link to relp.it - https://repl.it/@emmanuelpetrenk/Blockly-Test

Comment: The relp link gives a 404. Add a minimal complete example and we can possibly help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve